# What is ntdll.dll!RcConsolidateFrames?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dump, crash-dumps

I have a call stack like below from my dump file.
I want to find my code in the call stack, but I can't.
What is start point to analyze my dump?
Link option of my program is release/Od.

```
msvcr120.dll!abort() 
msvcr120.dll!terminate()
msvcp120.dll!_Call_func$catch()
msvcr120.dll!_CallSettingFrame()
msvcr120.dll!__CxxCallCatchBlock(_EXCEPTION_RECORD * pExcept=0x0000002885f9b010)
ntdll.dll!RcConsolidateFrames()
msvcp120.dll!_Call_func(void * _Data=0x00000028835d5ce0)
msvcr120.dll!_callthreadstartex()
msvcr120.dll!_threadstartex(void * ptd=0x000000288366e410)
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()
```

Comment: RcCosolidateFrames is part of the exception handling code on Windows. Your program has some problem with its exception handling logic (like throwing a new exception when another exception is in progress or something).

Comment: thank you for your hint! I found a unhandled exception in my code.:)

Comment: I can see the exact same in WinDBG, is there a way to narrow down where the exception is occuring in the code using the dump?

Comment: @OliverCiappara - See the [link in my answer](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=110) for some more info (that I quite frankly cannot really follow). Maybe you can find something there whether it's possible to narrow the original location down from the info in the dump.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: If you re-`throw;` the call stack will not show the original location, but something further up the stack and `ntdll.dll!RcConsolidateFrames()`.

---

You will find `ntdll.dll!RcConsolidateFrames()` in your call stack for an unhandled exception instead of the actual location when the code uses `catch(ANYTHING) + throw;` [in an x64 binary](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=110).

You see, if you `catch` and re-throw, the original call stack *has been already unwound*, and when you then `throw;` it will re-throw the original exception, but the call stack information is now messed up.

My observations for MSVC is that this will always happen with any `throw;` that is then unhandled and leads to a dump file. Specifically:

- It does *not* matter whether you use `catch(...)` or `catch(cppTypeEx&)`
- It does *not* matter whether it is a C++ exception (with `/EHsc` or `/EHa`)  or a SEH exception (with `/EHa`).
- It will look like this in the debugger *as well* as in a dump file.

Bottom line: `throw;`will mess up your call stack

Comment: Do you know if there’s a way to get the original stack trace from certain types of exceptions like `winrt::hresult_error`? According to [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20221121-00/?p=107429) a `winrt::hresult_error` will record a stack trace for the current thread as part of being thrown as a "stowed exception", but I haven’t found a way to retrieve this stack trace.

Comment: @Frederik - well that would be quite a separate question, wouldn't it. I'm not familiar with winrt, but as Raymond mentions `Ro­Originate­Error` I'd start with the docs on that function. If you write up a separate question for this, it's fine to drop a link here.