# Strange Exception in WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am kinda lost with this since two months ago. I really can't figure out from where this is coming from. I thought it was a bug in the framework about concurrent garbage collection. So I disabled it. But I am still getting this. I am hoping I can find some insights from the community.

> Thread 20 - System ID 8552
>
> Entry point   clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc 
>       Create time   6/2/2016 7:37:30 AM 
>       Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.000 
>       Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.000
>
> This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.
>
> .NET Call Stack
>
> [[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]]
>
> Full Call Stack
>
> KERNELBASE!RaiseException+68 
>       MSVCR120_CLR0400!_CxxCallCatchBlock+169 
>       ntdll!RcConsolidateFrames+3 
>       clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+6c 
>       clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+75 
>       [[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]] 
>       clr!ManagedThreadBase_FullTransitionWithAD+2f 
>       clr!AppDomainTimerCallback+7f 
>       clr!ThreadpoolMgr::AsyncTimerCallbackCompletion+6d 
>       clr!UnManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+19b 
>       clr!ThreadpoolMgr::ExecuteWorkRequest+64 
>       clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+3b5 
>       clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+7d 
>       kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+22 
>       ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+34
>
> Exception Information
>
> In w3wp__DefaultAppPool__PID__2920__Date__06_02_2016__Time_07_37_52AM__167__First chance exception 0XE06D7363.dmp the assembly instruction at KERNELBASE!RaiseException+68 in C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll from Microsoft Corporation
>       This exception originated from MSVCR120_CLR0400!_CxxCallCatchBlock.  has caused an unknown exception (0xe06d7363) on thread 20
>
> This exception originated from MSVCR120_CLR0400!_CxxCallCatchBlock+169.
>
> Module Information
>
> Image Name: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll   Symbol Type:  PDB 
>       Base address: 0x00000003`00905a4d   Time Stamp:  Thu Mar 10 18:31:13 2016
>
>       Checksum: 0x00000000`00000000   Comments:
>       COM DLL: False   Company Name:  Microsoft Corporation 
>       ISAPIExtension: False   File Description:  Windows NT BASE API Client DLL 
>       ISAPIFilter: False   File Version:  6.3.9600.18264 (winblue_ltsb.160310-0600) 
>       Managed DLL: False   Internal Name:  Kernelbase.dll 
>       VB DLL: False   Legal Copyright:  Â© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 
>       Loaded Image Name:  KERNELBASE.dll   Legal Trademarks:
>       Mapped Image Name:     Original filename:  Kernelbase.dll 
>       Module name:  KERNELBASE   Private Build:
>       Single Threaded:  False   Product Name:  MicrosoftÂ® WindowsÂ® Operating System 
>       Module Size:  1.08 MBytes   Product Version:  6.3.9600.18264 
>       Symbol File Name:  c:\symbols\kernelbase.pdb\64DCF0F0326E4AD7A4397D79BA8A9BEE2\kernelbase.pdb   Special Build:  &

This is happening alone without the server getting any requests or anything. Just another test server requests a page at some time lapse to check the server is online. Aside from that nothing else happening. I have all the calls surrounded by try/catch but this is coming from unmanaged so the server just crashes and the watchdog starts it again.

Comment: Might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636764/clr-dll-exception-causes-the-iis-crashed-pdb-symbol-for-clr-dll-not-loaded-the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550207/what-are-the-causes-and-solutions-of-exception-code-c0000005-in-mscorwks-dll

Comment: Thanks but those are also coming from unmanaged code but are access violations. I am getting a c++ exception. I find this information interesting.

ntdll!RcConsolidateFrames+3 looks like some thread is started (Not by my code). Then looks like is trying to consolidate a heap and throws a c++ exception. Just guessing.

Comment: I was researching and that function has actually nothing to do with heap is about stack frames http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093439/what-is-rcconsolidateframes I guess a good question now is who created that thread that gives so little clues on the stack trace.